# Model, View, Controller confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Model-View-Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413879/understanding-model-view-controller)

I have a general programming question about how to divide up my code, usually (and I'm trying to get away from this) I just write it all in the viewController, lots and lots of code in the view controller. But now i've reviewed some information on the MVC but I have some questions.

**My Question**

Mainly, if I a view controller (holding a model and a view), and in the model I run a method figures out a number display for the view, so just a simple int which the view would take and display on the screen. In order for my model to tell my view to do this should I go straight from model ----> view. Or should I return the data back to the controller and then send it to the view?

Lastly, if I need to send the data back to the controller, how might I do so, because I thought that the model should'nt know about the controller, only vice-versa.

Sorry for the lengthy question. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: As per as i know for my understanding Model - *Your database*
View  - *your layout which you create using nib or pro grammatically *
Controller - * your UIViewController *

Comment: Since you tagged your question iOS, I think it is a very good point to look at the question @bzlm refers to. Apple's MVC differs quite a bit from what is normally meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of info about this in the net. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> Though MVC comes in different flavors, control flow is generally as
> follows:
>
> 1. The user interacts with the user interface in some way (for
>    example, by pressing a mouse button).
> 2. The controller notifies the model of the user action, possibly
>    resulting in a change in the model's state. (For example, the
>    controller updates the user's shopping cart.)
> 3. A view queries the model in order to generate an appropriate user
>    interface (for example the view lists the shopping cart's contents).
>    The view gets its own data from the model. In some implementations,
>    the controller may issue a general instruction to the view to render
>    itself. In others, the view is automatically notified by the model of
>    changes in state (Observer) that require a screen update.
> 4. The user interface waits for further user interactions, which
>    restarts the control flow cycle.
>
> The goal of MVC is, by decoupling models and views, to reduce the
> complexity in architectural design and to increase flexibility and
> maintainability of code. MVC has also been used to simplify the design
> of Autonomic and Self-Managed systems

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use bindings, you can simply have model-classes for your db-operations, views for your interfaceobjects and a controller, that retrieves data from the earlier and puts it in the latter and you're fairly structured. As for the way back: everything you app does, is triggered by one kind of event or another. According to those, you have to fetch the appropriate values from your interface (->outlets). For everything else, you'll actually have to do some further studying controllers and bindings.